# I can't delete a row from MS access database from VB.net

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

I'm trying to delete a row from MS database by following a [YT tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nse-xeFp0Og) but I got 2 kinds of errors. When I try this:

```
    Dim provider As String
    Dim dataFile As String
    Dim connString As String
    Dim myConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection

    provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="
        dataFile = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\PU\SEMESTER 4\Visual Programming\Hospital Databases\Patient DB.accdb"
    connString = provider & dataFile
    myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
    myConnection.Open()
    Dim str As String
    str = "Delete * from [Patient] Where [PatientID] = " & PatientID.ToString & ""
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
```

I got this error: "Malformed GUID in query expression '[PatientID]=DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { Name=PatientID, index=0 } '

So I used brackets as stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/error-using-special-characters) so now it's like this:

```
str = "Delete * from [Patient] Where [PatientID] = [" & PatientID.ToString & "]"
```

But this gave an error: "No value given for one or more required parameters". When I replaced the brackets with single quotes I also get this error.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378763/no-value-given-for-one-or-more-required-parameters/2378853), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519195/how-to-delete-records-of-ms-access-database-using-vb-net-form-and-how-to-enter-a), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62502653/delete-selected-row-from-datagridview-and-ms-access-database) but still got an error.

Idk what to do.

EDIT:

I did `PatientID.ToString` because I want to make it so that when a user clicks on an ID cell, it will get the ID without the user having to input anything. But apparently that was wrong so I made an inputbox and followed Mary's answer. But I got this error on the `Execute...` line:
"No value given for one or more required parameters"

I searched and most of them said to put single quotes for it to work. I did (^) and still got that error :( Did I call the sub in the wrong way?

```
    Private Sub DischargeToolStripMenuItem1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DischargeToolStripMenuItem1.Click
        Dim ID As Integer
        ID = InputBox("Enter the ID of the patient to be discharged", "Discharge")
        DeleteRecord(ID)
    End Sub

    Sub DeleteRecord(ID As Integer)
        Dim provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="
        Dim dataFile = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\PU\SEMESTER 4\Visual Programming\Hospital Databases\Patient DB.accdb"
        Dim connString = provider & dataFile
        Using myConnection As New OleDbConnection(connString),
                cmd As New OleDbCommand("Delete * from Patient Where PatientID = @ID", myConnection)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = ID
            myConnection.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Sub
```

Comment: when you debug.print the value of str what do you get? A tip for you is to get the SQL query working in Access first, then use that as a guide to build the exact string needed. From this question it's likely that you just need this: Where [PatientID] = '" & PatientID.ToString & "'"

Comment: Based on the error message, `PatientID` is a column in a `DataGridView`. That means that not only are you using terrible, misleading names for things, you're using the wrong thing. If the actual value you want is in a cell in a row in grid then you need to get that value out of the cell of the row of the grid, not use the column. Also, stop using string concatenation to insert values into SQL code and learn how to use parameters.

Comment: it would be helpful if you showed us where ```PatientID``` is coming from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connections and commands need to be disposed. `Using...End Using` blocks will take care of closing connections as well as disposing connections and commands. In this code both the connection and command are included in the same block. Note the comma at the end of the first line of the `Using`.

Don't open the connection until the last possible moment, directly before the `.Execute...` line. Close the connection with the `End Using` right after that.

Always use parameters. With Access we use parameter names for ease of reading the code. Access pays no attention to the names. What is important is the order that the parameter appears in the sql query must match the order that the parameter is added to the parameters collection. I had to guess the datatype of the parameter. Check your database for the actual type.

```
Private Sub DeleteRecord(ID As Integer)
    Dim provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="
    Dim dataFile = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\PU\SEMESTER 4\Visual Programming\Hospital Databases\Patient DB.accdb"
    Dim connString = provider & dataFile
    Using myConnection As New OleDbConnection(connString),
            cmd As New OleDbCommand("Delete * from Patient Where PatientID = @ID", myConnection)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = ID
        myConnection.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

User input should always be validated. A user may or may not enter something that can be converted to a number. Serveral datatypes have a `.TryParse` method to test with. `.TryParse` returns a `Boolean` so it fits right into an `If` statement. The first parameter string you want to test. The second parameter is a variable of the type you want to convert to. `.TryParse` will fill in the second variable with the converted value.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    'An InputBox always returns a String, not a number
    Dim ID = InputBox("Enter the ID of the patient to be discharged", "Discharge")
    Dim intID As Integer
    If Integer.TryParse(ID, intID) Then
        DeleteRecord(intID)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid number")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thankyou for answering, unfortunately I got an error on the `execute...` line and when I searched, most only suggested giving single quotes for it to work, but it still gave an error. I edited my question, did I call the sub in the wrong way?

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Comment: Did you check the datatype of PatientID in the database?

Comment: In access2010 the datatype is 'number' so I'm assuming integer. I tried validating it using `tryparse` and `convert.toInt32` but it still gave the error on the `execute` line.

Comment: @ConfusedCoder Have you tried running the query in the Access application? You might get a better explanation of the error.

Comment: @ConfusedCoder To check that the connection is opening properly, comment out the .Execute line.

Comment: You can check out the following [code sample](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/WorkingWithAccessDatabases/tree/master/BasicDeleteRecord) which does a delete operation

Comment: @Mary no I was not addressing you, I was addressing ConfusedCoder. I was simply indicating I had a working code sample that includes the database. It's on the same lines as yours.

Comment: @Mary I know about the @, in a comment only one is permitted. In regards to your answer, I would only know that if I tried it which I have not and was not the point of my initial comment was never had anything to do with you. I added my comment for one reason, there was no accepted answer thus I provided my code as an option.

Comment: @KarenPayne Your comment should have been posted to the OP's question not one of the answers. It was not a comment on the answer. Please delete and add in the appropriate place. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in the definition of datafile in that it is not reading the file name properly.  While I agree with others that using parameters is the best way to proceed, in the interim, try this:

```
Dim MyFile as string = "Patient DB.accdb"
Dim dataFile = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\PU\SEMESTER 4\Visual Programming\Hospital Databases\" & MyFile
```

Comment: I tried that and still got an error on the `execute` line so I don't think so.